# Cómo un callback de un modelo a una variable?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, callback

Estoy tratando de almacenar un `callback` de la siguiente función:

```
Item.find(function (err,items){

})
```

en una variable de la siguiente forma

```
var item = Item.find(function (err,items){
    return items
})
```

pero me sale que esto

```
undefined
```

cómo podría hacer esto, ya que se me anidan mucho las funciones

Comment: ¿Item es un array? En caso de ser así, la función que recibe el método find dice que el primer parámetro es el valor, el segundo el índice que corresponde a ese valor y el tercero el array mismo. En tu ejemplo, de ser Item un array estás intentando devolver el índice, si no hay elementos retornas 0 que es lo mismo que false, por lo tanto retorna undefined.

Comment: No entiendo a lo que te refieres con "callback", si los que quieres es el resultado lo tienes dentro de la funcion como la variable items, si lo que quieres es una forma alternativa de almacenar el resultado te sugiero que investigues sobre async y await

Comment: Justo he estado investigando acerca de lo que me dijiste con async await. Me ha servido para lo que he estado buscando Daniel.

Comment: Por otro lado, ddenis, mi módulo sí tiene elementos. Pero me no entendí la parte que comentaste del tercer elemento de la función. Osea que debo retornar la tercera variable para obtener el objeto que estoy buscando?